# Select numbers from a list with given probability p

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say I have a list of numbers [1, 2, 3, ..., 100]. Now I want to select numbers from the list where each number is either accepted or rejected with a given probability 0 < p < 1 . The accepted numbers are then stored in a separate list. How can I do that?
The main problem is choosing the number with probability p. Is there an inbuilt function for that?
The value of p is given by the user.

Comment: This is not clear enough for me. Can you add a detailed example ? Can you also indicate what you tried ?

Comment: eg given the list [1, 2, 3, ...,100] . I want to run over each element of this list and select each element independently with probability p. And I will store the selected elements in a separate list. The main problem is selecting or rejecting the element with probability p. Rest all is easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [random.random()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) and a list comprehension:

```
import random

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

k = [x for x in l if random.random() > 0.23] # supply user input value here as 0.23

print(l)
print(k)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

to check each element of the list if it has a probability of > 0.23 of staying in the list.

---

Sidenote:

[random.choices()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) has the ability to accept weights:

```
random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
```

but those only **change the probability inside the given list** for drawing one of the elements (absolute or relative weights are possible) - thats not working for "independent" probabilities though.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for :)